# JavaScript function results in undefined

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a simple JavaScript function which should either return `true` or `false`.

Instead, it keeps returning `undefined`.

My code:

```
function usernameCheck($username) {

    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/cp/login.php',
        data: {username: $username},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
            // If I console.log() here it shows the correct value (true)
        }
    });
}

// $u is the value of an input field (e.g. test)
// This console.log() shows undefined.
console.log(usernameCheck($u));
```

Comment: What is the result of `console.log($u);`?

Comment: @user3378165 `test`

Comment: it's an async function inside. can you replace `success: function(data) { return data;` with `success: function(data) { console.log('success'); return data;`? and test it?

Comment: @NinaScholz Shows `success` and `undefined` in the console.